# How to make config.properties file be accessible after deploying war?

Tags: java, war, filenotfoundexception

Code is working fine while running from eclipse but after creating war using maven and deploying the same it shows the following expection so where to put the file so that its is accessible even after war deployment.

```
<ns0:ServiceCall2Response xmlns:ns0="http://files/">
     <return><![CDATA[<Response><RESP_STTS>800</RESP_STTS><RESP_DESC>java.io.FileNotFoundException: src\main\resources\config.properties (The system cannot find the path specified)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:146)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:101)
at files.DownloadDocInFileImpl.ServiceCall2(DownloadDocInFileImpl.java:124)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.WLSInstanceResolver$WLSInvoker.invoke(WLSInstanceResolver.java:117)
at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.WLSInstanceResolver$WLSInvoker.invoke(WLSInstanceResolver.java:91)
at com.sun.xml.ws.server.InvokerTube$2.invoke(InvokerTube.java:149)
at com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.SEIInvokerTube.processRequest(SEIInvokerTube.java:88)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:1136)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:1050)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:1019)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:877)
at com.sun.xml.ws.server.WSEndpointImpl$2.process(WSEndpointImpl.java:419)
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit.handle(HttpAdapter.java:868)
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.handle(HttpAdapter.java:422)
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.ServletAdapter.handle(ServletAdapter.java:169)
at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.WLSServletAdapter.handle(WLSServletAdapter.java:199)
at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.HttpServletAdapter$AuthorizedInvoke.run(HttpServletAdapter.java:640)
at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:363)
at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:146)
at weblogic.wsee.util.ServerSecurityHelper.authenticatedInvoke(ServerSecurityHelper.java:108)
at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.HttpServletAdapter$3.run(HttpServletAdapter.java:284)
at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.HttpServletAdapter.post(HttpServletAdapter.java:293)
at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.JAXWSServlet.doRequest(JAXWSServlet.java:128)
at weblogic.servlet.http.AbstractAsyncServlet.service(AbstractAsyncServlet.java:99)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:844)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:280)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:254)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:136)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:346)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:243)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3432)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3402)
at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2285)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2201)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2179)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1572)
at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:255)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:311)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:263)
```

test.pdf]]>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify resources in your pom.xml

```
<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/resource-directory.html

**OR** 
use Maven war Plugin with resources

```
<build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <webResources>
            <resource>
              <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
          </webResources>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

**Loading Properties**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;


public class PropertiesUtil {


    private static void loadProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        try {
            properties.load(PropertiesUtil.class.getResourceAsStream("/config.properties"));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok.. lets see if it works .. Ill get back to you in a bit.

Comment: I just created a maven config and ill share the automatically generated pom with you .. let me know then.

Comment: here goes the pom.xml --

Comment: <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </resource>
      <resource>

Comment: <directory>src</directory>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
          <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        </configuration>

Comment: <resources>
<resource>
    <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
    <filtering>true</filtering>
</resource>
</resources>

Comment: No , your code worked but i am getting a different exception now.

Comment: Sounds good, lets resolve that @SiddharthBhatia Details please

Comment: Ok cool .. I am getting  a Message Send failed : SOAPExceptionImpl and also a request timeout.

Comment: Ok i am reading the url of the service i am consuming from the properties file in the file it is mentioned as TARGET.URL...and in the code it is as            url = prop.getProperty("TARGET.URL")

Comment: If you are sure the exception regarding config loading is resolved, you can close this and create a new thread(question) on SOAPException and request timedout and vote up my answer :)

Comment: anyhow you will get a vote up... but please help me resolve this one too..

Comment: Sure, I mean if you can post it as new question, it will be easy to understand and I will answer it

Comment: Ok ill do that and let you know.

Comment: I can only add after 90 mins.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a `FileInputStream` for reading the properties. If you want the configuration to be part of the WAR file, you'll need to make sure it's packaged and available on the classpath.

If you're using maven, for example, place the `config.propertues` file in the `src/main/resources` folder. This will be packaged along with the code and will be accessible at runtime on the classpath and can be accessed like this:

```
InputStream s = WhateverClassInYourProject.class.getResourceAsStream("/config.properties");

Properties props = new Properties();
props.load(inputStream);
```

Comment: But it worked earlier .. i had to make some changes and after making those minor changes now I am facing this issue.